# How to call a Java function in a running Java app from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, function, libgdx, artificial-intelligence

I'm making a game in which you build robots and program AIs for them in JS. The main game is written in Java (LibGDX), but the AI will be made in JS (probably). To get variables from the main game and make the robot move from the JS file, I'll use functions to call another function in the game.

One, for example, is `r-getXpos(); // Gets the health of the robot`: this will be called from the JS file and will call a function in the Java app which will then return the robot's health for use in the JS file.

Is this even possible to do? If not, how should I do something like this?

Comment: Javascript runs on browser and Java for your system runs on server. So you can't call java functions directly. You should send request to Servlets and get response from servlets.

Comment: I'm guessing the LibGDX feature to 'deploy' the game for HTML 5 will be used?

Comment: I guess you should take a look at Rhino (or Nashorn if you are running java 1.8). Rhino/Nashorn is the JavaScript-Engine for Java. I guess you will find some tutorials on how to use it. I never used it myself, so i can't tell you how to use javascript within java.

Comment: @YusufK. JavaScript does not need to run on browsers. Java has a JavaScript Engine (Rhino/Nashorn) and i guess thats what he is looking for. Also the Libgdx Javacode, when targeting HTML5, is "converted" to javascript using gwt, so it should also run on the client.

Comment: @ZacG if you are looking for something as pointed by Springbua, forget about servets, I don't notice the libgdx tag ;)

Comment: Have you taken a look at the LibGDX AI library? If this fits your needs then staying within LibGDX should be a lot simpler. https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-ai/wiki

Comment: I'm pretty sure it won't. The idea in my game is the *player* will make an AI.

Comment: @ZacG so you should definitely take a look at Nashorn/Rhino documentation. If you also consider other Script-Languages, LuaJ would be an alternative to. This enables you to use Lua in Java. An example for Lua in Java is the ComputerCraft Mod for Minecraft.